# log4j LogManager.getLogger get's stuck in an infinite loop

Tags: java, log4j

For some strange reason, I have a line of code that is getting stuck in an infinite loop.
This is the line:

```
this.logger = LogManager.getLogger(getClass().getName());
```

A little context might be helpful:
I have a machine that stores all the code and java `.class` files. I access this machine through `sshfs` and work directly on the `.java` files through Eclipse.

If I login in the remote machine and execute my class, the code runs:

```
$ ssh remote-machine
$ cd /path/to/eclipse-project
$ export CLASSPATH="..." # A bunch of required libraries, including
                         # log4j-api-2.0-beta7.jar and log4j-core-2.0-beta7.jar
$ java path.to.MyClass
Welcome, please do stuff
>>>
```

If I use the `sshfs` file system mounted on my machine:

```
$ cd /mount-point/to/remote-machine
$ cd path/to/eclipse-project
$ export CLASSPATH="..."
$ java path.to.MyClass
<nothing happens>
```

I did, through Eclipse debugging, determine that `LogManager#getLogger` is the culprit. In fact, going a little deeper, I saw that there is a loop that starts with `index=2` and only terminates when `class==null`, in `ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:86`.

Comment: Do you have anything special in your log4j configuration which is causing this? Can you try changing the line to: `this.logger = LogManager.getLogger(YourClass.class);` and see if the same problem occurs?

Comment: I have a log4j2.xml file, but I think it is quite standard. If I replace with the class literal, I get the same behavior.

Comment: If its working on one system and not on the other, there must definitely be some issue on the other system. Check the configuration files and also any permissions if it should be writing somewhere.

Comment: On a separate note, (not saying that the issue is coming from there) log4j 2.0 is still beta, so expect some hickups. If you want something stable and still recent you might want to look at Logback instead. (Syntax is essentially the same except for `LoggerFactory` instead of `LogManager` and some differences in the config file). It also implements `slf4j` which is the common logging defacto standard.

Comment: Changing the line to `LogManager.getContext().getLogger(getClass().getName())` works, and I'm going to use this at the moment, but I'm not sure what the implications will be. Thanks for your comments.