# Log4j slow initialization with LogManager.getLogger and getContext()

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I experience a strange situation which similarly has been described in [LogManager.getLogger stalls Application for ~10-30 Seconds when using JDK8:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42830383/logmanager-getlogger-stalls-application-for-10-30-seconds-when-using-jdk8/46222261#46222261) but there is no solution proposed.

The thing is that the initialization of the logger through

```
final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(MyClass.class.getSimpleName());
```

stalls my application for almost 7s (on newest MacBook Pro 15" 2017) IF if have either WiFi disabled OR if I am tethering through my iPhone.
If, however, I have a working Internet connection through my WiFi (no tethering), the log4j initialization works within 1,5 s.
That is a very strange behaviour. First I thought that log4j tries to access a resource on the Internet and times out after a few seconds, but then again: why the same behaviour when I am tethering and thus have access to the Internet?

When debugging further, I found that this method is taking so long:

```
public static LoggerContext getContext(final boolean currentContext) {
    // TODO: would it be a terrible idea to try and find the caller ClassLoader here?
    try {
        return factory.getContext(FQCN, null, null, currentContext, null, null);
    } catch (final IllegalStateException ex) {
        LOGGER.warn(ex.getMessage() + " Using SimpleLogger");
        return new SimpleLoggerContextFactory().getContext(FQCN, null, null, currentContext, null, null);
    }
}
```

Especially this:

```
factory.getContext(FQCN, null, null, currentContext, null, null);
```

Does anyone have a clue why this happens and how I can solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I just met the same problem when I transfer my program from PC to MBP with JDK version 1.8.0_144 or 1.8.0_102.
I think this is a bug of JDK for Mac.

**U can work around it, with JDK version 1.8.0_31.**